# Adobe Flex : Get full menu path when sub menu is clicked?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flash-builder

IIs there any way to get the full "menu path" when a sub menu is clicked.  E.g. if I have a menu Devices->MODBUS->Input when "Input" is selected is there any way I can determine the "Devices->MODBUS" part?

TIA,
Fred

Comment: Please share some code.  I'm not sure what you mean by menu path.  Are you referring to the directory structure your SWF is served from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or by another way as below on MenuEvent.ITEM_CLICK event: -

```
private function menuHandler(event:MenuEvent):void
            {
                var pathArray:Array = new Array();
                pathArray.push(event.item.@label);

                var parent:XML = event.item.parent(); 

                while(parent != null)
                {
                    pathArray.push(parent["@label"]);
                    parent = parent.parent();

                }
                pathArray.reverse();
                trace(pathArray)
            }
```

Comment: copy / paste is so nice ? :))))) what is your answer different than mine ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using XML as dataProvider for your Menu control and also I suppose you are using the mx/s:Menu control. Else your question would be really confusing, and my answer out of scope.

You can listen for MenuEvent.ITEM_CLICK event and do the following:

```
// Event handler for the Menu control's change event.
private function menuHandler(evt:MenuEvent):void  {
    Alert.show("Label: " + evt.item.@label, "Clicked menu item");
    var path:Array  = new Array();

    var objXML:XML   = evt.item as XML;

    while(objXML)
    {
        path.push(objXML);
        objXML = objXML.parent();
    }

    path.reverse();

    // now you have the path from top to bottom, as array of xml elements.

}
```